# How to hide an element using php

Tags: wordpress

I have some elements that i hide using css display: none; functions, and most ones i hide using javascript, but when ever a user stripes or disables his browser css and javascript everything i hide will become visible on the front end, though the site may be looking scattered rhen but those hidden elements will still show as html files.. 
Any idea on how to hide such elements so that if javascript and css are disabled in the viewers browser  the hidden elements won't still show. 
I was thinking php can be used since there is no way to strip it off.

Comment: I am not sure how many people turn off CSS. Most of the popular sites we access also will look ugly without CSS. There are valid reasons to turn of Javascript in some contexts. Anyway, without CSS and Javascript, from PHP you can choose not to write the elements (possibly based on some condition). Note that PHP code is executed at server-side and you have full control on generated HTML. However, at the client side with Javascript and CSS (of enabled) you may alter what actually is displayed.

Comment: You can "hide" elements by wrapping them in an if statement, but there is no reliable method for determining if the user has disabled anything client side in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
<?php
  $flag=false;

  if($flag){
    ?>
    HTML code here, flag is true
    <?php
  }
  else{
  ?>
    HTML code here, flag is false
  <?php
  }
?>
```

This is not an efficient way to do it, but maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is rendered to the DOM might be found even if you have other means beside CSS/JS to hide it (you may simply analyse the entire server's response).

Therefore you may want to prevent entirely the HTML code that should not be shown to be sent through backend logic. An example:

```
<? $cond=false; if($cond): ?>
<p>I'm shown on <i>$cond === true</i></p>
<? else: ?>
<p>I'm shown when <i>$cond === false</i></p>
<? endif ?>
<p>I'm always shown</p>
<p style="display:<?= $cond ? 'none' : 'block' ?>">
    I'm always rendered but hidden/shown through CSS and $cond value
</p>
```

You can modify it here:
https://3v4l.org/pimd5 (press the eye button at the right to check the rendered HTML).

Comment: I will appreciate if we make it a simple hidden function without adding a condition to it, the id is to be hidden without any confitions like if or endif, please help with a straight php code to anchor the id or class on the php and then make it hidden by default.  i am looking at <?php $cond // (condition should be the id of the div i want hidden)
<p style="display: none;">
    I'm always rendered but hidden
?>

Comment: @pandglobal I'm not sure if I got it right, but if what is to show depends on an id, then `<?= $id ? "<p id='$id'>hi</p>" : "" ?>` would be enough...